# Pentaho job is not executing by running batch file

Tags: batch-file, pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon, pdi

I am using windows box. I installed PDI 6.0 and created a PDI job. I created a job.bat file and when I tried to execute the job in the shell, the job is not executing at all. But by using Pentaho Spoon, this job is totally working fine. I have no idea why it is not running in the windows command prompt using bat file. Here is the batch file I created

```
@echo off
cd D:\Pentaho\DataIntegration
SET WORK_DIR=D:\Work
SET LOG_FILE=%WORK_DIR%\log\job.log
SET JOB_FILE=%WORK_DIR%\PDI_JOB\job.kjb
SET DEV_SERVER=DEVDBSERVER
SET DEV_DB=devdb
SET DB_USER=dataadmin
SET DEV_DB_PWD=1HSFGD4426384VVJJKJCACACSFJWK
SET ENV=DEV
"D:\Pentaho\DataIntegration CE 6.0.1.0-386\Kitchen_6g.bat"   /file:%JOB_FILE% "-param:WORK_DIR=%WORK_DIR%" "-param:DEV_SERVER_LOCAL=%DEV_SERVER%" "-param:DEV_DB_RE=%DEV_DB%" "-param:DB_ADMIN_USER=%DB_USER%" "-param:DEV_DB_PWD_ADMIN=%DEV_DB_PWD%" /log:%LOG_FILE% /level:Detailed
@echo on'
```

I have no idea what is wrong with this script. If anyone can point out, it will be very appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, I have no idea either, it would be good to tell us what happens when you run it, then maybe I will have some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below code

> @echo off
>
> SET myparam=a123
>
> call D:\Development\data-integration70\kitchen.bat
> /file:D:\opt\CE\data-integration\weekly_data_transfer\testenv.kjb
> "/param:TestParam=%myparam%" --level=Minimal >>
> "D:\opt\CE\data-integration\weekly_data_transfer\log.log"
>
> @echo on

Comment: thanks for the reply. But I want to pass the value through batch file. that is why I am passing value through batch file.

Comment: ok, if you want to set parameter value, you can use above code. I have updated my earlier code.