# Passing a list as a parameter Pentaho

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have problem with use kitchen.bat in Pentaho.
I want to set parameters in form: 'test1','test2'.
I'm trying:

```
Kitchen.bat /rep:git /dir:TestCase/test /job:Job_1 "/param:ENV=QA" "/param:SOURCE=FIN" "/param:table_name='table1','table2'"
```

But when I see in log then I see that the list parameter is not passed. Anyone know how to set this up?

[image]

Comment: You can see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63365471/pentaho-job-is-not-executing-by-running-batch-file/63391680#63391680

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see my sample job and bat file, where i call the job using parameter value 'table1','table2' and also received that value from my job [Here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Tao6WexGiAXc6CD-0sPPE2LwZi2ePqYq?usp=sharing)

D:\Development\data-integration70>"C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe"  "-Xms2024m" "-Xmx6048m" "-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m" "-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" "-Djava.library.path=libswt\win64" "-DKETTLE_HOME=" "-DKETTLE_REPOSITORY=" "-DKETTLE_USER=" "-DKETTLE_PASSWORD=" "-DKETTLE_PLUGIN_PACKAGES=" "-DKETTLE_LOG_SIZE_LIMIT=" "-DKETTLE_JNDI_ROOT=" -jar launcher\pentaho-application-launcher-7.0.0.0-25.jar -lib ..\libswt\win64  -main org.pentaho.di.kitchen.Kitchen -initialDir "D:\opt\CE\data-integration\weekly_data_transfer"\ /file:D:\opt\CE\data-integration\weekly_data_transfer\testenv.kjb "/param:table_name='table1','table2'" --level Minimal